# Математические операции с Generics Java

Tags: java, generics

есть потребность в написание, некоторых математических примитивов, наподобие векторов и матриц... Хотел использовать дженерики, но столкнулся с проблемой, что к ним нельзя применять математические операции также как и в С++, вот пример:

```
public class VectorX2<Type> {

    private Type x;
    private Type y;

    ...

    public void add(VectorX2<Type> another) {
         this.x += another.x;
    }

}
```

Также пробовал и следующее:

```
public class VectorX2<Type extends Number> {

    private Type x;
    private Type y;

    ...

    public void add(VectorX2<Type extends Number> another) {
         this.x += another.x;
    }

}
```

Но все также безрезультатно... Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как это можно избежать или сделать лучше или все-таки придется жестко привязываться к определенным типам?

Comment: На Java, это, вроде, сделать невозможно. А вот на Kotlin может получиться. Попробуйте тут посмотреть, вроде аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534074/kotlin-generic-addition

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [Apache Commons Math](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3), и не пишите велосипеды (:

Comment: Ну я же не спрашивал про то, что какие существуют библиотеки для этого. Я спрашивал как это можно реализовать...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class VectorX2<Type extends Number> {
    private Type x;
    private Type y;

    public VectorX2(Type x, Type y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void add(VectorX2<? extends Number> another) {
        Number n = x.doubleValue() + another.x.doubleValue();
        x = (Type) n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "VectorX2{" +
                "x=" + x +
                ", y=" + y +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VectorX2<Integer> v = new VectorX2<>(1, 2);
        System.out.println("v = " + v);

        v.add(new VectorX2<>(3, 4));
        System.out.println("v = " + v);
    }
}
```